# Value of Transient Name Identifier in SAML Response

Tags: saml-2.0

If a SAML Response has subject name identifier as Transient, how its value is calculated?

I have seen examples like:

3f7b3dcf-1674-4ecd-92c8-1544f346baf8

If any body could guide me how the value 3f7b3dcf-1674-4ecd-92c8-1544f346baf8 is calculated. Is it a random value or derived out of any logic.

Thanks in advance....

Regards,
Ashu

Answer (score 0):

This does mostly depend on whan implementation your using. The SAML specification only specifies small things as uniqness and length See 1.3.4 in the [SAML core specs](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf)

It also makes recommendation to use a reandom number. So that is probably how it is implemented in most implementations